# React Context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola tengo un todo list hecho en react pero, me surge una duda con el codigo que implemente. en el **provider** contuve todos los states propios del todo app como users: [] y name: '' ademas de todas las funciones que tenia el **form**. mi pregunta sobre esto es ¿es sano colocar el form y los metodos del form dentro del provider? **adjunto código**:

***//provider:***

```
import React from "react";

export const ContextoApp = React.createContext();

class TodoProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      users: [],
      handleData: this.handleData,
      handleSubmit: this.handleSubmit
  };

  this.handleData = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  };

  this.handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
      name: this.state.name
      };
    this.setState({
      users: this.state.users.concat(newItem)
      });
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.handleData(e)} />
        <button>Agregar</button>
      </form>

      <ContextoApp.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ContextoApp.Provider>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoProvider;
```

Mi componente consumer sera **lista.js**  este componente sera renderizado en app dentro de los tags de el componente mi provider

```
import React from "react";
import { ContextoApp } from "./contexto/context-todo";

export class Lista extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>lista usuarios</h1>
        <ul>
          <ContextoApp.Consumer>
            {valueState => {
              return valueState.users.map((user, index) => {
                return <li key={index}>{user.name}</li>;
              });
            }}
          </ContextoApp.Consumer>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal sería que crearás contextos más específicos, osea uno para user, otro para form y así...,esto es porqué componentes que estén consumiendo el contexto no serán renderizados por datos que no usan, dándote una mejora en rendimiento en dichos componentes, espero te sea de ayuda